# Split String in 3 By REGEX Groups

Tags: perl

I haven't worked with PERL for many years and I'm more than a little out of practice.

I'm matching a line in a file based on a regex and search string, when the line matches I do some 'stuff' but where I'm getting stuck is when I try to split the line into 3 variables, where

```
$one = before the match
$two = the match
$three = after the match.
```

Here's some code that works:

```
(my $one = $line) =~ s/(^.+)($search)(.+$)/$1/;
(my $two = $line) =~ s/(^.+)($search)(.+$)/$2/;
(my $three = $line) =~ s/(^.+)($search)(.+$)/$3/;
```

But it would be a little more cool if I could do it in one line.

I've tried many variations of the following 2 ideas

```
my ($one, $two, $three) = $line =~ /(^.+)($search)(.+$)/;
my ($one, $two, $three) = split(qq|/$search/|,$line);
```

I've googled, I've PERLDOC'd, I've rummaged in the basement and dug out PERL IN A NUTSHELL and a few other O'REILLYs that I haven't seen in years. I don't know why I cannot get this to do what I want.

perl -v tells me

> This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
> (with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

and I'm on  Mac OS X 10.13.6

Any insight would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: The name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually provided the answer:

```perl
my ($one, $two, $three) = $line =~ /(^.+)($search)(.+$)/;
```

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'
   my $search = "b";
   my $line = "abc\n";
   my ($one, $two, $three) = $line =~ /(^.+)($search)(.+$)/;
   say for $one, $two, $three;
'
a
b
c
```

But like your original code, the above could have problems with inputs that contain line feeds, and it will find the latest-starting match instead of the earliest-starting one. The following is truer to your intent:

```perl
my ($one, $two, $three) = $line =~ /^(.*?)($search)(.*)/s;
```

Finally, neither of the above work without adjustment if `$search` can contain captures. If that's possible, you could use either of the following:

```perl
my ($one, $two, $three) = ( $line =~ /^(.*?)($search)(.*)/s )[0, 1, -1];
```

```perl
my ($one, $two, $three) = $line =~ /$search/ ? ($`, $&, $') : ();
```

Comment: I thought ikegami was wrong when he said I had provided the answer with 
my ($one, $two, $three) = $line =~ /(^.+)($search)(.+$)/;

So I copied his one-liner and it returned the right output. I copied into a file and it ...it returned the right output.
So I went and looked at mine, and....it is the same...so wtf?

The error must lie elsewhere. Something must be clobbering that $line.

Thanks ikegami and @jo-37.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to capture the matching groups of the `s///` operator, you may use something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.16;
use warnings;

my $line = 'abc';
my $search = 'b';
my $new = $line =~ s/^(.+)($search)(.+)$/$2/r;
my @match = map substr($line, $-[$_], $+[$_] - $-[$_]), 1 .. $#-;
say $new;
say "@match";
```

which gives:

```
b
a b c
```

This does not modify the original string and it's a bit clumsy.

Comment: Re "*This does not modify the original string*", okay? Neither does the OP's working code.

Comment: Your code is better written as: `my @match = $line =~ /^(.+)($search)(.+)$/; my $new = $match[1];` It has a few possible problems (doesn't handle line feeds, finds the lastest-starting match instead of the first, `@match` could have more than three elements).

Comment: My intention was to show a way to access the matching groups from a `s///` operator, independently from the substitution taken. I had the impression this was the question - probably an over-interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using Zero width assertion of Perl regular expressions(without the use of search string).
You can use,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$string = "ABCD";
@split = $string =~ /(?=(\w{1}))/g;
print "@split\n"
```

This will give you an array with elements A,B,C and D.